# How can I efficiently retrieve linked rows in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wcf, nhibernate

Assume I had these tables in my database that is queried by a web service (WCF) via NHibernate:

```
Table "Patients"
  Column "Id"
  Column "LastName"
  Column "FirstName"
  Column "Age"

Table "Treatments"
  Column "Id"
  Column "PatientId"
  Column "Name"
  Column "IsActive"
```

A patient can have any number of treatments. If I wanted to gather a list of patients with their currently active treatments, how could I most efficiently achieve that in NHibernate?

Currently, I'm doing this (with SetFirstResult() and SetMaxResults(), of course):

```
var patientsWithTreatments = new List<PatientWithTreatments>();

var patients = Session.CreateCriteria<Patient>().List<Patient>();
foreach(Patient patient in patients) {
  patientsWithTreatments.Add(
    new PatientWithTreatments(patient) {
      Treatments = Session.CreateCriteria<Treatment>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("PatientId", patient.Id)).List<Treatment>()
    }
  );
}
```

Which involves a round-trip to the database per patient in the result set, which is a pretty bad idea. Is there some magic with plain NHibernate queries or will I have to use HQL (which I don't have a firm grasp of yet) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate has the option to add relationships behind the scenes (meaning they're known to NHibernate but not exposed to code) via `access="noop"` in the mapping file.

These can then supposedly be used like any normally declared relationship in HQL.

As of NHibernate 3.1.0, for me this had the slightly inconvenient side-effect of completely deleting all of the referenced rows from the other table right when the query is run, so you might want to double-check before using `access="noop"` in production code.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to have a collection in your Patient class called Treatments. In your nHibernate mapping you should have something like:

```
<many-to-one name="Treatments" column="TreatmentID" class="Treatment" fetch="select" cascade="none"/>
```

Then you can retrieve all the Treatments from the Patient by:

```
List<Treatment> treatments = yourPatient.Treatments;
```

Comment: Yes, that is one option. What I'm interested in, though, is to know how I can achieve this with NHibernate's Criteria API (or HQL if necessary) if I do not want to expose the relationship in my domain classes (the actual code would make this a bit harder because the relationship goes over a second table)

Comment: You could try using Aliases and then a ProjectionList within Criteria, but I'm not sure if this would work without the 'Treatments' being unmapped. You could always just map the Treatments and mark them as 'lazy loading' improving the efficiency.

Comment: With that I'd be back on square one: a round-trip to the database for each lazily loaded treatment that turns my 0.5 second query into a monster that takes multiple minutes to complete...